# Using UIPanGestureRecognizer to swipe down UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, uipangesturerecognizer

I have an `IBAction` for a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` in my `UIView`, I am able to handle the gesture and recognise the state changes from began, cancelled and ended, as well as respond to those changes.

However when using the `sender.location` to handle the swipe down, the `UIView` actually moves up once the gesture has began, and then continues to move down. The experience is jarring and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Does anybody have any ideas ?

```
func update(_ translation: CGPoint, origin: CGPoint) {

    let offSetY = translation.y

    cardView.frame.origin.y = offSetY

    let multiplier = 1 - (translation.y / 2000)
    self.view.alpha = multiplier
}


func cancel(_ origin: CGPoint) {

    let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.6, dampingRatio: 0.6) {
        self.visualEffectView.alpha = 1
        self.cardView.alpha = 1.0
        self.view.alpha = 1.0
        self.cardView.center = origin
    }
    animator.startAnimation()
}

func finish() {
    let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.9, dampingRatio: 0.9) {
        self.visualEffectView.effect = nil
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    animator.startAnimation()
}



@IBAction func panGestureAction(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    self.view.backgroundColor = .white
    let originalCardPosition = cardView.center

   //let cardOriginY = cardView.frame.origin.y
    let translation = sender.translation(in: self.cardView)
    let origin = sender.location(in: self.cardView)

        switch sender.state {
        case .changed:


            if translation.y > 0 { update(translation, origin: origin) }

        case .ended:

            let translation = sender.translation(in: self.cardView)

            if translation.y > 100 {

                finish()

            } else {
                cardView.alpha = 1.0
                cancel(originalCardPosition)

            }
        case .cancelled:
            cancel(originalCardPosition)

        default: break
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you set the `origin.y` of the `cardView` directly to the value of `translation.y`. You need to add `translation.y` to the view's original `y` value determined when the gesture begins.

Add a property to the class:

```
var originalY: CGFloat = 0
```

Then in the `.began` state of the gesture, set it:

```
originalY = cardView.frame.origin.y
```

Then in your `update` method you set the origin:

```
cardView.frame.origin.y = originalY + offSetY
```